# Drop Database connections in MS Sql Server 2000

Tags: sql-server-2000

I have a database that we are having problems with.  Somehow the log has became 400 Gb and the database has been rendered useless.  I want to drop all existing connections to the database and then detach the database.

Basically what I'm going to do is get rid of the giant log file and create a new one and reattach if it works.  If not, we're going going to restore from backups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well basically no commands would execute agaisnt the database, at all.  What we ended up doing was turning off the service and creating empty copies of the mdf and ldf files and replacing the ones being used by sql server.  After that we restored the database from the last backup and voila, it's working again (mostly).

Answer (score 1):

If the log is useless, you can use these commands, but please document on them yourself before applying on a production server.

BACKUP LOG WITH NO_LOG   for disgard the pages from log,

sp_helpdb  for looking the name of the files of the db

DBCC SHRINKFILE('your log filename ', 0)  -- for trunking the physical file to the size specified.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure there are no open transactions you can put the database in single user mode.

ALTER DATABASE [YourDB] SET SINGLE_USER WITH NO_WAIT

When you are done put it back in multi user mode
ALTER DATABASE [YourDB] SET MULTI_USER WITH NO_WAIT

Does

backup log yourdb with truncate_only then dbcc shrinkdatabase(yourdb) not shrink the logfile for you ?

Comment: dbcc shrinkfile fails to find the log file, even though i know i'm typing the name right.  Trying the use command just runs continiously.

Comment: In management studio check the activity on the database it may be that you are locked out of it by another process; if there were open when you single user-ed the database then transactions it may be rolling back or some other internal process.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER DATABASE [DB_NAME_HERE] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE

ALTER DATABASE [DB_NAME_HERE] SET MULTI_USER
```